# Using grep cmd to filter

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Using grep or egrep

How many email addresses are in ‘first.last’ name format AND involve someone
whose first name starts with a letter in the first half of the alphabet?
(I want to get the count)

excerpt of testingfile.txt

```
glorious@uole.com
hhhhhh
ItzStatic
jackass
The_Epic_Turtle
david.webb@cia.gov
overthemoon34
smiley362
emilio
rico@uole.com
ddc44ever
check.it@geocities.com
dickens@uole.com
middle614
IntegrityJeff
5432
jdm-mojo@geocities.com
zack.gertrude@gmail.com
```

To do this I wanted to filter each line to check if it had a "@" and check the first letter to see if it was A-M or a-m, and check if it had a period.

`grep -c "@" testingfile.txt`

`grep -c "\." testingfile.txt` (although this only checks if there is 1 occurrence in the line.)

`grep -c "[a-mA-M]" testingfile.txt` (still haven't gotten this one to work)

How would I combine the 3 statements together, and how would I check to see if the first character of each line is a letter between a-m or A-M?

Comment: Two options: 1) regexp ( try [Regexr](http://regexr.com/) for building the query)   2) use pipe `|` and put greps one after another

Comment: @the.Legend I'll use pipes. Would it be like this? grep -c "@" | grep -c "\." testingfile.txt
Also, how can I get the 3rd one to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Finding email addresses that start with [a-mA-Z]

Because you were interested in the problem of more than one email on a line, let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat testingfile.txt 
glorious@uole.com
hhhhhh
david.webb@cia.gov overthemoon34 rico@uole.com
Check.it@geocities.com dickens@uole.com
IntegrityJeff
5432
jdm-mojo@geocities.com
zack.gertrude@gmail.com
```

This shows the first parts of all the matching email addresses whose first letters are in the first half of the alphabet:

```
$ grep -o "\b[a-mA-M][^[:blank:]]*@" testingfile.txt 
glorious@
david.webb@
Check.it@
dickens@
jdm-mojo@
gertrude@
```

This counts them:

```
$ grep -o "\b[a-mA-M][^[:blank:]]*@" testingfile.txt | wc -l
6
```

#### Being more strict about the "first" name

If we want to restrict the match to email addresses whose name part includes a period:

```
$ grep -o "\b[a-mA-M][^[:blank:]]*\.[^[:blank:]]*@" testingfile.txt 
david.webb@
Check.it@
```

And to count them:

```
$ grep -o "\b[a-mA-M][^[:blank:]]*\.[^[:blank:]]*@" testingfile.txt | wc -l
2
```

#### Notes

1. The regex used here, `\b[a-mA-M][^[:blank:]]*@` is quite simple.  Regexes exist that accurately select true email addresses but they are quite complex.
2. `grep -c` counts lines.  We first have to use `grep -o` to put each match on a separate line and then use `wc -l` to count the lines.
3. The regex `[a-mA-M]` is not unicode-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 grep "^[a-mA-M].*\..*@" testingfile.txt
```

This will search for a string where it starts with the first half of the alphabet (`^[a-mA-M].*`) Then, at some point contains a period (`.*\.`) and then at some point later has a `@`:  (`.*@`).